# Removing diacritics (accents) from strings. Help me resolve

Tags: c#, asp.net

****Errors:****
 1. Program does not contain a static Main method suitable for entry point
 2. The Modifier static is not valid for this item
 3. The variable 'RemoveDiactritics' is declared but never used

```
class Program
{

        public static void Main(string[] args)

        {

            static String RemoveDiacritics(String s)


            {
                String normalizedString = s.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD);
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                for (int i = 0; i < normalizedString.Length; i++)
                {
                    Char c = normalizedString[i];
                    if (CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(c) != UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark)
                        stringBuilder.Append(c);
                }

                return stringBuilder.ToString();
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Please add a valid code for this program to get output

Answer (score 1):

```
class Program
  {

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RemoveDiacritics("foobar");
    }


        static String RemoveDiacritics(String s)


        {
            String normalizedString = s.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD);
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            for (int i = 0; i < normalizedString.Length; i++)
            {
                Char c = normalizedString[i];
                if (CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(c) != UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark)
                    stringBuilder.Append(c);
            }

            return stringBuilder.ToString();
        }

 }
```

Comment: What is ("foobar"); in this program?

Comment: entry text for your method RemoveDiacritics()

Comment: Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: I got this output alone

Comment: That is because while `RemoveDiacritics` does return a string value, the Main ignores it. So catch that return value in some variable and "Console.WriteLine" it.

Comment: Can i get the program for that pls